# Sequence contains no elements : self referencing code first

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

when I try to do self referencing with next entities

```
public class Folder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int?  ParentFolderId { get; set; } // Added property
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Folder> Childrens { get; set; } // Added property
    public virtual ICollection<ArticleTitle> ArticleTitles { get; set; }

}


public class ArticleTitle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int? FolderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Folder Folder { get; set; }
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
}
```

I added few properties (commented 'added property')  and this line of code:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Folder>()
 .HasMany(s => s.Childrens)
 .WithOptional()
 .HasForeignKey(s => s.ParentFolderId);
```

And get this exception:

**Sequence contains no elements**

Is it not correct self referencing?

Comment: where are you getting the error

Comment: when initialized database (DropCreateIfModelChanges)  Context context = new Context(); context.Database.Initialize(true);

Comment: Try adding `public virtual Folder ParentFolder { get; set; }` and then setting the foreign key attribute above `ParentFolderId` like this: `[ForeignKey("ParentFolder")]`

Comment: I add your code and  remove fluent api binding and  Childrens property and than all work.Thanks.

Comment: please make as answer.

Comment: ok, I'm glad it helped, but if you don't like configuring with `DataAnnotations` you should look for a way of achieving this with Fluent API, I'm sure it can be done ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your code should look like:

```
public class Folder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentFolder")]
    public int?  ParentFolderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Folder ParentFolder { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Folder> Childrens { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ArticleTitle> ArticleTitles { get; set; }

}
...
```

I'm glad it helped.