# Self Referencing table creating it's own Parent_ID column which breaks my mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following class:

```
public class Page : BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PageID { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Page Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Page> Children { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<int, string> PossibleParents
    {
        get
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> items = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            items.Add(-1, "Please Select");

            using (var context = new WebsiteContext())
            {
                var pages = context.Pages;
                foreach (var p in pages)
                    items.Add(p.PageID, p.Name);                    
            }

            return items;
        }
    }

    public Page()
    {
        this.Order = 0;
        this.Live = false; 
    }
}

public class CommodityPageMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Page>
{
    public CommodityPageMap()
    {
        HasOptional(x => x.Parent)
            .WithMany(x => x.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

**Problem**

I assumed that it would map `ParentID` to link a Page to a parent Page. It seems however that upon updating the database EF has created `Parent_PageID`. Now when I set `ParentID` it's not creating the association properly and `Parents` doesn't contain any elements because `Parent_PageID` is null.

**I have tried**

If I remove `ParentID` then it won't compile as it's needed to set the Foreign Key. I can't add the Data Annotation `[Column("Parent_PageID")]` to `ParentID` as this produces an error at run time when accessing `PossibleParents` and it seems silly to add `Parent_PageID` to my model and ignore `ParentID`.

I assume I am missing something but would appreciate some assistance.

Edit

I have just tried adding the following:

```
public int? ParentID { get { return this.Parent_PageID; } set { this.Parent_PageID = value; } }
public int? Parent_PageID { get { return this.ParentID; } set { this.Parent_PageID = value; } }
```

but this raises `Sequence contains no elements` when trying to access `PossibleParents`.

Comment: I haven't tried this with Code First, was your mapping set before you first generated the table? What's the run time error when using the Column annotation you suggested?

Comment: Yes, all my mapping was in place before generating the table. The error I get is `Sequence contains no elements` when accessing `PossibleParents`.

Comment: Did you add the `CommodityPageMap` to the modelBuilder?

Comment: No, I didn't realise I had to do that. I thought it was just "automagically" called as it wasn't mentioned in the post I read: http://www.codecapers.com/post/Using-Self-Referencing-Tables-With-Entity-Framework.aspx.

Comment: No, there is no magic for this :) You need `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CommodityPageMap());` in `OnModelCreating` of your derived `DbContext` class.

Comment: Ah Ok, it's hard to tell sometimes with all the automatic things happening behind the scenes which bits need managing manually! Will I need to rebuild my data base after making this change?

Comment: Doing this creates `Sequence contains no elements` when running `Page page = db.Pages.Find(id);` or `return View(db.Pages.ToList());`.

Comment: Do you still have this stuff in your "Edit" in place? You should remove it and return to your original model. Also, can you try `db.Database.Initialize(true)` as the very first call to EF before any query and check if it also throws the same exception. It would indicate that somewhere else the mapping is incorrect.

Comment: I don't have my edits in my code. It did indeed cause the same exception. Also, I saw this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857203/sequence-contains-no-elements-self-referencing-code-first and the fix there also doesn't work. p.s Really appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: Ok sorted it. I changed my model to use `Parent_PageID` and removed the `ParentID` mapping. I then followed the advice in the link above and added `[ForeignKey("Parent")]` above `Parent_PageID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve my issue although I don't know why using Fluent API was causing issues.

I changed my code replacing `ParentID` with `Parent_PageID`. I then added `[ForeignKey("Parent")]` Data Annotation to `Parent_PageID`. My code ended up like this:

```
public class Page : BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PageID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int? Parent_PageID { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public bool Live { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SEOTitle { get; set; }
    public string SEODescription { get; set; }
    public string SEOKeywords { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public virtual Page Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Page> Children { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<int, string> PossibleParents
    {
        get
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> items = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            items.Add(-1, "Please Select");

            using (var context = new WebsiteContext())
            {
                var pages = context.Pages;
                foreach (var p in pages)
                    items.Add(p.PageID, p.Name);                    
            }

            return items;
        }
    }

    public Page()
    {
        this.Order = 0;
        this.Live = false; 
    }
}
```